# Kibana can't reach elasticsearch

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Using docker-compose v3 and deploying to a swarm:

```
version: '3'
services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
     - "9200:9200"
    tty: true


  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.4.1
    deploy:
      mode: global
    ports:
     - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    tty: true
```

I see this in the kibana service log:

> Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/

Elasticsearch service is running and can be reached.
Swarm consists of 3 nodes.

What am I missing?

**Update:** 
I turns out that if I try to access kibana on the same swarm node where elasticsearch is running, it works. All other nodes either have a network problem or cannot resolve the elasticsearch name.

Comment: Are they on the same network?

Comment: Yes they are. I tried defining a network specifically for them as well as using the default network like the compose file above. I also inspected both services to verify network settings. It's like the kibana nodes cant resolve the 'elasticsearch' name.

Comment: It works when I deploy the stack to my local machine in swarm mode (only one swarm node). But not on the swarm that has 3 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose by default generates a network and puts all services within it. But I do not know if it changes in docker swarm. To define it you can do this.

```
version: '3'
services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
     - "9200:9200"
    tty: true
    networks:
      - some-name


  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.4.1
    deploy:
      mode: global
    ports:
     - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    tty: true
    networks:
      - some-name

networks:
  some-name:
  driver: overlay
```

I hope it serves you, I will wait for news.

Comment: Still the same. Check the update I added to the question.

Comment: I was reading a little docker swarm documentation, and there seems to be a way to create a network between nodes to run through services. You have to add the "overlay" driver.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, and the solution.
My swarm is running on AWS - All nodes are placed in the same security group and I assumed all ports were open internally in that security group. That's not the case.
I explicitly configured the security group to allow inbound traffic as per dockers routing mesh specs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/